# Change Attribute of the attribute value based on the responsive size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

i have the following twitter widget code

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/youtube" data-widget-id="672009634018758656" data-link-color="#e36b5c" data-height="500" >#youtube Tweets</a>
                <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

In the responsive mobile devices i want to change `data-height="500"` to 350.
Do i need to have duplicate code or can i change this dynamically based on the device width

```
pageHeight = $(window).height();
    pageWidth = $(window).width();

    if(pageWidth < 767){

    }
```

Comment: Change it based on device width dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to calculate it within resize event:

```
$(function(){
   var value2upd = function(){
       var w = $(window).width();
       return w < 767 ? 350 : 500;
   };

   $(window).resize(function(){
       $('.twitter-timeline').attr('data-height', value2upd);
   }).resize(); // <-----------fires when dom is ready.
});
```